# Why is my forEach prototype for my mockup framework not working?

Tags: javascript

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3WpNG/17/

I'm just making a framework (For learning purposes) and I'm trying to add a forEach method, so when I call `ezWork().class('big').forEach(function(element) { console.log(element) });`

It will do what it is supposed to do, but I'm getting errors, any information would be great, this is my code so far :

```
var ezWork = (function (win, doc) {

    function EzWork(element) {
        this.element = this.iD(element);
    }

    EzWork.prototype = {
        iD: function (element) {
            return document.getElementById(element);
        },

        on: function (event, callback, override) {
            var attach = window.hasOwnProperty('addEventListener'),
                meth = attach ? 'attachEvent' : 'addEventListener',
                prefix = attach ? 'on' : '';
            if (!override) {
                this.element[meth](prefix + event, callback, false);
            } else {
                this['on' + event] = callback;
            }
            return this;
        },
        class: function(element) {
         return doc.getElementsByClassName(element);   
        },

        forEach: function() {
            if(!Array.prototype.forEach) {
                Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
                    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len ; i += 1) {
                         fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    //
    return function (element) {
        return new EzWork(element);
    }
})(window, document);

console.log(ezWork().class('button'));

ezWork().class('button').forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

`Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'forEach'`

Comment: What errors (apart from the obvious syntax errors) do you get? Also check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility

Comment: @Bergi http://jsfiddle.net/3WpNG/18/ check the console.log `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'forEach' `

Comment: Your `.class()` method does return the `NodeList` from `doc.getElementsByClassName()`, which will have no `forEach` method as it is no array! Didn't you want to return another `EzWork` instance for chainability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use the console next time. The error is as clear as day from there.

```
for(var i = 0; len = this.length; i < len ; i += 1)
//           ^---- this should be a comma
```

---

Here's [a rough example](http://jsfiddle.net/3WpNG/21/) of wrapping:

```
function EzWork(element) {
    //stores the data into an instance property
    this.element = element;
}

EzWork.prototype = {
    class: function (element) {
        //wraps the result into the instance and returns the instance
        return new EzWork(doc.getElementsByClassName(element));
    },
    forEach: function (fn) {

        var instance = this;

        //run through the data in the instance
        for (var i = 0, len = instance.element.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            fn.call(instance.element, instance.element[i], i, instance.element);
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3WpNG/18/ thanks for that catch, but I'm getting an error, check the console log, forEach not defined?

Comment: @XCritics I just changed the semicolon to a comma from your posted fiddle. [**Nothing like that happened**.](http://jsfiddle.net/3WpNG/19/) What else did you change there?

Comment: Check the new fiddle in this comment

Comment: @XCritics because your `class` method returned what `getElementsByClassName` returns, a NodeList, which naturally has no `forEach` method.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, that's why I'm wondering how to get my forEach prototype to work

Comment: @XCritics Then you wrap the data as an instance of your framework. That way, it carries your prototype. Just for comparison, a jQuery object is actually an array-like object containing an "array" of wrapped data. It's wrapped so that one could access jQuery methods via it's prototype.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to edit my fiddle to give me an example of what you mean would you?